# Does TextRenderer.DrawText() can be used in WEB Application (C#.NET )?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-7

Hello Everyone
 Can anyone tell me is it possible to use "TextRenderer.DrawText()" in WEB Application (C#.NET ) for text text rendering in GDI and saving the text as image.
Please Help. thanks.

Comment: You've asked 7 questions and accepted 0 answers. You might want to do something about that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can do this with the Generic Http Handler template. Essentially you create a GDI Image in memory, create a memory stream and send it down the http stream from the Http Handler. In the web page you will need an img tag and set your http handler as the image src. This will cause the browser to make a request to the handler, which will render the image and send it down the wire to be rendered in the browser.

This method is often used to watermark images for a website.
See this link for some detail:
[dynamic image (from db) using Generic Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231246/dynamic-image-from-db-using-generic-handler)