# Mapping image with Entity Framework

Tags: database, image, entity-framework

I have an MVC Application that uses Entity Framework to comunicate with database.

I want to get an image that is saved in the DB and load it on screen, but I can't figure out the way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Pedro

Comment: This post describes one possibility http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231246/dynamic-image-from-db-using-generic-handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably save the image in the database with a byte array, then you must use System.Drawing.Image class to convert the byte array that came from the DB.

Consider "imageFromDb" as the array from the database.

```
using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imageFromDb)))

{
  // Do the job that you want with the image.
}
```

Wish you Luck :)