# How to retrieve image fields civilimage1,civilimage2 from SQL Server database to show using image control in ASP.NET with vb.net or c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have some images in a SQL Server database byte array and I want to retrieve those images in ASP.NET. but i dont get images.Picture are write inside the folder but i cant sow them in image controller.

Please solve my problem.

```
Private Sub CusImgShow1()
{
    Const SQL As String = "SELECT civilimg1 , civilimg2 FROM [NewCus] WHERE [Cust_ID] = @Cust_ID"
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(SQL, myConnection)

    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cust_ID", Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString("Cust_ID")))
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

    Try
            If dr.Read() Then
                Dim image As String = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime()) & "1"
                Dim image3 As String = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime()) & "2"
                Dim fs1 As New FileStream(("~/CRM/imagesb/" & image), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
                Dim fs2 As New FileStream(("~/CRM/imagesb/" & image3), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
                Dim bimage1 As Byte() = DirectCast(dr("civilimg1"), Byte())
                Dim bimage2 As Byte() = DirectCast(dr("civilimg2"), Byte())
                fs1.Write(bimage1, 0, bimage1.Length - 1)
                fs2.Write(bimage2, 0, bimage2.Length - 1)
                fs1.Flush()
                fs2.Flush()
                Image1.ImageUrl = "~/CRM/imagesb/" & image
                Image2.ImageUrl = "~/CRM/imagesb/" & image3
           'Dim base64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bimage1, 0, bimage1.Length)
                'Image1.ImageUrl = Convert.ToString("image/JPEG") & base64String
            End If

            myConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
}
```

Comment: Remember that the image will delivered as part of a completely separate http request. All you need to do in the page is provide enough information to the image control that you'll know what image you want in that other request. However, you will also need to build a handler for that request. That's where the real work is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamic image (from db) using Generic Handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231246/dynamic-image-from-db-using-generic-handler)

Answer (score 0):

1) Create an Handles (.ashx) file that gets Image name from querystring and send the image to the browser

```
public class Myandler : IHttpHandler
{
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  {
     byte[] fileBytes;
     string fileName;

     //...get from byte[] from SQL Server

       context.Response.Clear();
       context.Response.ClearContent();
       context.Response.ClearHeaders();
       context.Response.Buffer = true;
       context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
       context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
       context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
       context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
       context.Response.Flush();

  }
 }
```

2) Into the HTML page

```
 <img src="MyHandler.ashx?ImageId=123">
```

Note: sorry, my code is c#....
Note 2: this is just a sample answer.. you can encrypt querystring, validate user etc etc

Comment: You don't need to do `HttpContext.Current`. Look at the parameter being received by the function. Just directly use the `context`. And you shoud try to use the correct MIME type rather than `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: without handlers is possible to create display images from database?